# Housing Materials, Structure and Style in the late Middle Ages in Germany

Tags: middle-ages, germany, architecture

So my friend and I are coming to develop an Age of Empires-esque game set in the late Middle Ages. Like any good developers we're doing our research first and we've come up with some issues. When trying to research pre-Tudor (Note, I'm using this as a time reference, not trying to imply Tudor occupied Germany as I have no idea if that was a thing or not) housing the majority of information that comes up is about Tudor housing, and pictures demonstrate iconic styles associated with the Tudors.

Our questions are:

- What materials were used in the construction of housing? We understand that the richer you were the more likely your house was to be stone, and less likely to use clay and earth as a mortar, but specifics are hard to come by.
- What layout did the buildings take? The more basic housing would be single rooms, we assume, but what rooms generally took precedence and would the more expensive housing generally follow specific layouts?
- Gothic architecture is renowned for its arches. Where there any pre-Tudor architectural norms or flagstone shapes that would have been common?

Any help is greatly appreciated as well as any resources we can use to help educate ourselves!

As you might be able to appreciate we'd like to ensure its not horrendously inaccurate, and besides- Its a good excuse to learn!

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than searching for "Pre-Tudor" anything, especially anything not England, you should simply use "Late Medieval" as the keyword. In general mixing national periodisations are not going to work very well. Googling Late Medieval German housing immediately returns links like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_German_house) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but when searching I didn't try to find "Pre-Tudor" examples of architecture, but rather looked for "Late Middle Ages German housing" which does return Tudor-esque housing which is why I used this terminology.

**Edit:** Granted, the examples I see that I would generally associate with the Tudors may be true examples from pre-1480s but I don't know if that is the precursor to the Tudor style or not, and as such correction in that regards would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm just saying "Pre-Tudor" makes no sense at all in your context and you should probably stop using it when talking about Germany. Also, "Late Middle Ages German housing" in fact returned that link as a top result for me, which seem to be an exact answer for most of your question.

Comment: I understand that now. Also, I see that is the first link, however, that is more of an example of a singular type of housing. The aim of my question was to get a broader overview of the topic, rather than just focusing on animal rearing subcultures such as those who would have lived in an Einhaus. This would ideally extend to include those living in prosperous cities who had other occupations to farming.

Comment: Could pre-Tudor be used as a legitimate term in terms of architectural history/chronology? As I understand Tudor is also an architectural style? I'm not sure if that's the usage the author intended but something that piqued in my mind from a childhood love for architecture

Comment: No.. it's an example of the sort of prevailing structures central German peasants lived in. There are regional equivalents such as the Low German House too. @Anaryl In *English* architecture, yes. But as a searching tip, it is usually more effective to search a period by name, than as pre-anything. In the context of English architecture, it would be "Perpendicular English" as opposed to "Pre-Tudor".